# Get value of Nested JSON column

Tags: sql, json, oracle

I have the following:

```
WITH json AS (  
   SELECT '{"date":"2019-02-14"
        ,"data":{"AAPL":{"open":"169.71","close":"170.80","high":"171.26","low":"169.38","volume":"21175371"}
               ,"MSFT":{"open":"106.31","close":"106.90","high":"107.29","low":"105.66","volume":"21621821"}}}' doc  
   FROM dual  
)  

SELECT jt1.*
FROM 
json j,  
json_table(j.doc, '$'
       COLUMNS
       CLOSE_DATE varchar2(200) PATH '$.date'
     , NESTED  PATH '$.data[*]'  COLUMNS (
       ticker varchar2(2000) PATH '$.*',
       NESTED PATH '$.*' COLUMNS
                     (                       
                        opn   VARCHAR2(2000) PATH '$.open',
                        clse  VARCHAR2(2000) PATH '$.close',
                        hgh   VARCHAR2(2000) PATH '$.high',
                        lows  VARCHAR2(2000) PATH '$.low',
                        volu  VARCHAR2(2000) PATH '$.volume'
                     )                   
                    )
                   ) jt1;
```

It returns all values except for the two Stock Symbols. How can I get those values? I am using ORACLE XE 18C

Comment: what's doc doing over on RHS!

Comment: You seem to want to extract the ticker symbols as values. In the JSON they appear as attribute names. Don't try for a convoluted and error-prone workaround to make attributes to appear as values; rather, as Marmite Bomber shows in his answer, change (or get the source from which you receive the JSON to change) the JSON structure.

Answer (score 0):

With your data you may *flat* extract both *stock symbols* in separate columns named after the stock symbol.

```
WITH json AS (  
   SELECT '{"date":"2019-02-14"
        ,"data":{"AAPL":{"open":"169.71","close":"170.80","high":"171.26","low":"169.38","volume":"21175371"}
               ,"MSFT":{"open":"106.31","close":"106.90","high":"107.29","low":"105.66","volume":"21621821"}}}' doc  
   FROM dual  
)  
SELECT jt1.*
FROM 
json j,  
json_table(j.doc, '$'
       COLUMNS 
       CLOSE_DATE varchar2(200) PATH '$.date'
     , NESTED  PATH '$.data'  COLUMNS (
       NESTED PATH '$.AAPL' COLUMNS
                     (                       
                        AAPL_opn   VARCHAR2(2000) PATH '$.open',
                        AAPL_clse  VARCHAR2(2000) PATH '$.close',
                        AAPL_hgh   VARCHAR2(2000) PATH '$.high',
                        AAPL_lows  VARCHAR2(2000) PATH '$.low',
                        AAPL_volu  VARCHAR2(2000) PATH '$.volume'
                     ) ,
       NESTED PATH '$.MSFT' COLUMNS
                     (                       
                        MSFT_opn   VARCHAR2(2000) PATH '$.open',
                        MSFT_clse  VARCHAR2(2000) PATH '$.close',
                        MSFT_hgh   VARCHAR2(2000) PATH '$.high',
                        MSFT_lows  VARCHAR2(2000) PATH '$.low',
                        MSFT_volu  VARCHAR2(2000) PATH '$.volume'
                     )                     
                    )
                   ) jt1;
```

But this will not scale for more data.
What you probaly want is an array containing the *stock symbol* in it.

Note the changed JSON data

```
WITH json AS (  
   SELECT '{"date":"2019-02-14"
        ,"data":[{"ticker":"AAPL","open":"169.71","close":"170.80","high":"171.26","low":"169.38","volume":"21175371"}
               , {"ticker":"MSFT","open":"106.31","close":"106.90","high":"107.29","low":"105.66","volume":"21621821"}]}' doc  
   FROM dual  
)  

SELECT jt1.*
FROM 
json j,  
json_table(j.doc, '$'
       COLUMNS (
       CLOSE_DATE varchar2(200) PATH '$.date'
     , NESTED  PATH '$.data[*]'  COLUMNS 
                     (  ticker VARCHAR2(2000) PATH '$.ticker',                      
                        opn   VARCHAR2(2000) PATH '$.open',
                        clse  VARCHAR2(2000) PATH '$.close',
                        hgh   VARCHAR2(2000) PATH '$.high',
                        lows  VARCHAR2(2000) PATH '$.low',
                        volu  VARCHAR2(2000) PATH '$.volume'
                     ) 
                    ) 
                   ) jt1;
```

result

```
CLOSE_DATE           TICKER               OPN                  CLSE                 HGH                  LOWS                 VOLU               
-------------------- -------------------- -------------------- -------------------- -------------------- -------------------- --------------------
2019-02-14           AAPL                 169.71               170.80               171.26               169.38               21175371             
2019-02-14           MSFT                 106.31               106.90               107.29               105.66               21621821
```

Comment: I can't change the json. SELECT j.close_date,  
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(j.json_str, '"([A-Z]{4})":{"open":', 1, occurence, null, 1) ticker,  ......FROM   json d,  
       json_table(d.doc, '$'  
                  COLUMNS close_date VARCHAR2(12) PATH '$.date',  
                          json_str   VARCHAR2(4000) format json PATH '$.data[*]',                    The only issue is if the ticker is greater than 4 characters